# Angular2 - ngIf in a ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I want to check if the actual element has a value or not.

For Example I want to check if the chocolate is black or white. Depending on this, I want to display the right text.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let chocolate of product.getChocolates();">
     <md-card *ngIf="chocolate.getName() == black">IT IS BLACK</md-card>
     <md-card *ngIf="chocolate.getName() == white">IT IS WHITE</md-card>
</ng-container>
```

How to fix the code, so that it works?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is you missed `'`(single quote) behind `string` which is `black` & `white`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let chocolate of product.getChocolates();">
     <md-card *ngIf="chocolate.getName() == 'black'">IT IS BLACK</md-card>
     <md-card *ngIf="chocolate.getName() == 'white'">IT IS WHITE</md-card>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div *ngFor="let chocolate of chocolates">
     <div *ngIf="chocolate.name == 'black'">IT IS BLACK</div>
     <div *ngIf="chocolate.name == 'white'">IT IS WHITE</div>
</div>`
})
export class AppComponent{
  chocolates:any=[{
    name:'black'
  },
  {
    name:'white'
  }];

  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: sorry but I dont understand your question, can you be more specific?

Comment: i guess if i dont need to write the html code in the .html-file if i wrote it in the @Component({...template:...}) , but i need to reference the template in the html code?

Comment: instead of template write  templateUrl: './component.html'. Please suggest my answer as the solution, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let chocolate of product.getChocolates();">
     <md-card *ngIf="chocolate.getName() == black">IT IS BLACK</md-card>
     <md-card *ngIf="chocolate.getName() == white">IT IS WHITE</md-card>
</ng-container>
```

modify `chocolate .getName()` to `chocolate.getName()`